# How to do MATLAB OO nested naming elegantly?

Tags: matlab, oop, nested

My idea is to have generic components with generic subcomponents (generic because this is a framework that others will use) within it

```
classdef Component < handle
    properties
        Subcomponents
    end

    methods
    end
end
```

But the drawback of this is the naming sucks:

```
comp1 = Component;
comp1.Subcomponents.subcomp1 = Component;
```

When I actually want:

```
comp1 = Component;
comp1.subcomp1 = Component;
```

And the classes still know that subcomp1 is a subcomponent of comp1. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

In other words, I'd like to do e.g. `Car.Wheel1` and `Car.Wheel2` instead of `Car.Subcomponent.Wheel1` and `Car.Subcomponent.Wheel2` but Car still knows that Wheel1 and Wheel2 are its nested subcomponents and can call some of its methods.

**UPDATE:**

I consider this **resolved**. I used dynamicprops and it is wonderful now. I have a structure and still maintain ease in troubleshooting. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Generally in OO you want to restrict direct access to Object fields - have you considered using getter methods?

Comment: I'm alright with the separation of components i.e. Top.Sub{1}.Sub{1}.Sub{2}. However, it is not human-readable and I don't mind building an intepreter for this but still don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can define fields of `struct` on the fly, Matlab does not allow to do the same with object properties. So it seems you are stuck here ...

... but ...

there is a workaround ! Matlab developers have introduced in the recent releases some [methods that modify the default behavior](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/methods-that-modify-default-behavior.html). In particular, the methods `subsref` and `subsasgn`, which can handle your problem. Let's see how this can answer your question.

First, define you class `Component`:

```
classdef Component < handle
    properties
        Subcomponents
    end

    methods
    end
end
```

Then, you have to add the following methods `subsasgn` and `subsref`:

```
function this = subsasgn(this, S, B)

switch S.type
    case '.'
        if isprop(this, S.subs)
            this.(S.subs) = B;
        else
            this.Subcomponents.(S.subs) = B;
        end

end
```

and

```
function B = subsref(this, S)

switch S.type
    case '.'
        if isprop(this, S.subs)
            B = this.(S.subs);
        else
            B = this.Subcomponents.(S.subs);
        end
end
```

and this is it ! You can now define a `Component` object and play with its `Subcomponents` without interfering with the standard syntax for classical properties:

```
comp = Component;
comp.sub1 = Component;
comp.sub2 = Component;
c = comp.sub1;
```

However, please note that the default display of `comp` won't give you any information on subcomponents themselves:

```
>> comp
comp = 

  Component with properties:

    Subcomponents: [1x1 struct]
```

You can fix this by overloading the `display` method of your class.

Last but not least: `subsasgn` and `subsref` allow you to control the syntax of your objects (parenthesis, brackets, etc.), so there are much more cool things you can do with these two methods !

Comment: This is a really unnecessary approach. Overloading `subsref` and `subsasgn` is an advanced technique that is rarely needed unless you have a specific need to modify the referencing and assignment behaviour of object arrays. It's certainly not needed here. By the way, it's also not functionality that has been recently introduced: it's been around for many releases now.

Comment: PS If you do need to add or remove class properties on the fly, the way to do this is to inherit from `dynamicprops`, not to overload `subsref` and `subsasgn`. And to customise display, it‘s better if possible to inherit from `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` than to overload `display`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. However, which is easier to implement? dynamicprops or subsref/subsasgn? Also, which is easier to debug?

Comment: @SamRoberts: I don't agree. The OP asked for a specific syntax and I proposed an answer that fits this syntax. Your solutions (either a property array or deriving from `dynamicprops` and using `addprop`) _impose_ a different syntax.

Comment: @Ratbert that's right, my solution does use a different syntax. Although you've given a technically correct answer to the question, I wanted instead to guide the OP toward a different solution that (although it might need some changes to the class design) would be simpler, more idiomatic in MATLAB, and less prone to confusion than overloading `subsref` and `subsasgn`, which can get very hard very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just making the `subcomponents` property an array, so that you can say

```
comp = Component
comp.subcomponents(1) = Component
```

Comment: Accessing a subcomponent like a wheel would be Car.subcomponents(1) ? How can I use it's name such that it would be Car.Wheel1

Comment: Well if you want, you can have a property `wheel1`, set to be a `Component`, and then you can also have a property `subComponents` that is an array. If you want, you can set the `subComponents` property to be `Dependent` and `SetAccess=private`, and give it a `get` method that returns you an array containing `wheel1` and any other subcomponents you've defined.